# Jupyter lab doesn't open a notebook

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter lab on a server. I have recently reinstalled it using `pip-autoremove` and got a new issue: some `.ipynb` files which were created prior to the reinstall are not opening, they just display a blank page (as if there are no cells) and I am unable to run the code. At the same time jupyter logs just spam the following:

```
[E 2023-02-11 10:01:18.559 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/yjs/json:notebook:47dee2d6-9ed3-42b0-b765-dd14ef0d9928 (188.132.162.66)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='35.188.218.231:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/yjs/json:notebook:47dee2d6-9ed3-42b0-b765-dd14ef0d9928', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='188.132.162.66')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/jeff/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 944, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
      File "/home/jeff/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server_ydoc/handlers.py", line 222, in open
        if self.room.document.source != model["content"]:
      File "/home/jeff/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_ydoc/ydoc.py", line 26, in source
        return self.get()
      File "/home/jeff/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_ydoc/ydoc.py", line 166, in get
        metadata=meta["metadata"],
    KeyError: 'metadata'
```

I have installed jupyterlab with `pip install jupyterlab` which should make it the most recent version, but just in case here is the `jupyter -version` output:

```bash
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.10.0
ipykernel        : 6.21.1
ipywidgets       : 8.0.4
jupyter_client   : 8.0.2
jupyter_core     : 5.2.0
jupyter_server   : 2.2.1
jupyterlab       : 3.6.1
nbclient         : 0.7.2
nbconvert        : 7.2.9
nbformat         : 5.7.3
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.9.0
```

I am launching jupyterlab using `jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --no-browser --collaborative` to ensure that it is always on the port which is accessible and that I can use the notebook with other people.

I am not sure what could be causing this issue, because making a duplicate of the notebook fixes it entirely, but inspecting the code and permissions of the two resulting files reveals that they are absolutely the same. What could be causing this?

Bug report: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/13966